# Openni ROS: Get RPY?

Tags: ros, openni

Does the Openni drivers publish RPY? Checking the topic list, it does not seem to be the case.

I've tried looking at the /tf topic but it's values don't seem to change

Comment: As far as I know, the driver is not responsible for the pose of the camera... for that you will need a SLAM algorithm or something similar that will find the pose of the camera and publish it. The driver should only give you the rgb and color image and disparity images or pointclouds.... I THINK the tf from the driver is the extrinsic parameter of the camera with respect to the robot